# Get text file values, split it, output it in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a project where I have to output the contents of a text file into a JTextArea by clicking a button, but the contents of the text file are separated by `;` here is an example: `2.32;123,864,432.23;`.
I have to split contents of the text file and then output it in a text area. I'm having difficulties in doing so because the my code errors when I put in the code `textbox1.append(title);` . Can anyone help me find a solution?

Here is my code

```
btn1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
                filechooser.setDialogTitle("Select text file");
                filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);       
                
                File openfile = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream (openfile); 
                } catch (FileNotFoundException d) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    d.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (fis));
                
                String line = null;
                try {
                    line = br.readLine();
                    
                    while (line != null) {
                    String[] text = line.split(";");
                    textbox.append(text); 
                    line = br.readLine();
                    } 
                    
                } catch (IOException f) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    f.printStackTrace();
                }
            
                
                try {
                    br.close(); //closes the file
                } catch (IOException g) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    g.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] for your problem, as this code snippet does not provide the necessary information to help you. Also, you talk about "errors", but you don't provide the error text or stacktrace.

Comment: Furthermore, what is `textbox1`? In your question text you talk about a `JTextField`, but `JTextField` does not have an `append` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append every `String` in your `split` array individually, not the array itself.

```
Stream.of(line.split(";")).forEach(textbox::append);
```

If you want to do more with the split text, you can also use a for loop:

```
for(String part:line.split(";"))  {
    textbox.append(part);
    textbox.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I have another question, I want to put new lines between the values. Where should I put it? I'm really new to java and that syntax of code is something I do not know. Thank you

Comment: The first one is done with Streams and Lambda functions. You should look through a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams-introduction).